# Best way to call a method of a parent class from an object

Tags: python

I created a python script to create an IRC client.

I now would like to add a chat bot functionality to it.

So, my python script for my IRC client has quite a few methods in it and is looking rather large so I thought maybe it would be better to create a chatbot object that can read the message events from the IRC client and send messages when appropriate. I am I thinking about this in the correct way?

```
class IRCClient:
#client code
myGreetingBot = GreetingBot()


def SendToIRC(self, message):
     # send code implemented here
     # getting here from the created object is a problem

while 1:
    # this main loop continously checks a readbuffer for messages and puts them into a buffer
    #event driven method calling with IRCClient
    if ("JOIN" == buffer[1]):
        myGreetingBot.process(message)


class GreetingBot():
    def process():
        #getting here isn't a problem
        self.SendMessage()

    def SendMessage():
        # here I want to call the SendToIRC() function of the class that created this object
```

Sorry if that isn't very clear but maybe it demonstrates a) what I am trying to achieve and b) I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do with the indents broken. Paste the code back in, then select it and press the `{}` button on the [edit] toolbar to indent it all the proper 4 spaces

Comment: The code won't run, I just wrote it as I was thinking about the problem. I'm really just asking the best way to extend the funcionality of my base class. Maybe I just need to read up more on inheritance in python.

Comment: Um not a parent class, though I get what you mean. You need to pass the client to the constructor of GreetingBot() (or adda property and set that) and store it in a member, then you can call any methods on it via that member

Comment: You haven't used inheritance, and it's far from clear whether you should. Is a  GreetingBot an IRCClient (inheritance) versus has a GreetingBot an IRCClient (aggregation)

Comment: As Tony said, I don't think inheritance is the right choice here. As a rule, inheritance should always model an 'IS-A' relationship between the parent and child classes. So in this case, you would want inheritance only if the following is true: "GreetingBot is an IRCClient". That isn't the case, though. You're modeling a 'HAS-A' relationship, which, as Tony mentioned, is aggregation or encapsulation.

Comment: At the moment the greeting bot doesn't exist I'm trying to work out how to write one in a clean way to extend the functionality of my IRC client which I have already written. The client currently just establishes a connection to the IRC server and reads messages from it and is able to send messages to it using a socket.

Answer (score 0):

`IRCClient` is not a parent of `GreetingBot` or vice versa. All you have is a class which contains an instance of another

To achieve subtype polymorphism and have `GreetingBot` be a child class of `IRCClient`, you need to extend from the parent class like so:

```
class IRCClient:
   # write all the standard functions for an IRCClient.. Should be able to perform unaware of GreetingBot type
   ...

class GreetingBot(IRCClient):
   # GreetingBot is extending all of IRCClient's attributes, 
   # meaning you can add GreetingBot features while using any IRCClient function/variable
   ...
```

As for the title "Best way to call a method of a parent class from an object",.. if GreetingBot is a child of IRCClient you can already call every IRCClient function from a GreetingBot instance. If you want to however add more code to a function (for example `__init__`), you can do something like this:

```
class IRCClient:
   def __init__(self):
       # do IRCClient stuff
       ...

class GreetingBot(IRCClient):
   def __init__(self):
       # call parent initialize first
       super(GreetingBot, self).__init__()
       # now do GreetingBot stuff
       ...
```